# Как создать лист из кортежей в shell script либо итерировать сразу через два листа?

Tags: html, list, shell

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

**Моя задача:** Мне нужно создать html файл с варирирующим количеством картинок. Причем к каждой картинке прилагается ссылка. Такого типа:

```
<a href='$graph_url' >
  <img src='$graph_picture'>
</a>
```

Лист(ы) с сылками и лист с путями к картинкам генерируеться заранее.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли в shell возможность создавать кортежи как в python? пара данных которая обрабатываеться как один обект: ($graph_url, $graph_picture)

Из них я бы мог создать лист и создавать вышеуказанные html вставок:

```
list=(u1,p1) (u2,p2) (u3,p3)
```

**Вопрос 2:** Есть ли возможноть итерировать сразу через два листа? Тогда я бы мог в качестве альтернативы создать два листа и добиться того же результата. "for i in list" явно не подходит.

Буду благодарен любой идее которая меня продвинет вперед.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, так:

```
#!/bin/bash

u=("u1" "u2" "u3")
p=("p1" "p2" "p3")

for i in $(seq 0 $((${#u[*]}-1))); do
  echo "<a href='${u[$i]}'>"
  echo " <img src='${p[$i]}'>"
  echo "</a>"
done
```

результат выполнения:

```
<a href='u1'>
 <img src='p1'>
</a>
<a href='u2'>
 <img src='p2'>
</a>
<a href='u3'>
 <img src='p3'>
</a>
```

---

здесь:

- `${#x[*]}` — количество элементов в массиве `x`
- `$(($x-1))` — вычитание единицы из значения переменной `x`
- `seq x y` — получение последовательности натуральных чисел `x, x+1, ..., y`
- `${x[$y]}` — получение элемента номер `y` из массива `x`

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Можете объяснить почему в $(($x-1)) используються две скобки?

Comment: это [posix-овый синтаксис арифметического выражения](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)

Comment: нашел. "$((" заставляет shell рассматривать внутренность как арифметическое выражение, а не как групирующий знак