# Замена или генерация строк в nginx.conf на основе переменных окружения при помоши скрипта

Tags: nginx, bash, shell

Есть 5 пар переменных:

```
ROXY_HOST1=192.168.88.61:10001
PROXY_HOST2=192.168.88.61:10002
PROXY_HOST3=192.168.88.61:10003
PROXY_HOST4=192.168.88.61:10004
PROXY_HOST5=192.168.88.61:10005
PROXY_PASS1=http://192.168.88.59
PROXY_PASS2=http://192.168.88.59
PROXY_PASS3=http://192.168.88.59
PROXY_PASS4=http://192.168.88.59
PROXY_PASS5=http://192.168.88.59
```

Их нужно при помощи shell скрипта перидать в секцию конфига Nginx:

```
    location /___PROXY_HOST1___ {
    proxy_pass '___PROXY_PASS1___';
    } 

    location /___PROXY_HOST2___ {
    proxy_pass '___PROXY_PASS2___';
    }

    location /___PROXY_HOST3___ {
    proxy_pass '___PROXY_PASS3___';   
    }

    location /___PROXY_HOST4___ {
    proxy_pass '___PROXY_PASS4___';   
    }

    location /___PROXY_HOST5___ {
    proxy_pass '___PROXY_PASS5___';   
    }
```

Банально проблему решил так:

```
#!/bin/bash
### Proxy pass and upstream name replacment part 
sed -i "s?___PROXY_PASS1___?${PROXY_PASS1}?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_PASS2___?${PROXY_PASS2}?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_PASS3___?${PROXY_PASS3}?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_PASS4___?${PROXY_PASS4}?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_PASS5___?${PROXY_PASS5}?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

### Server part replace 
sed -i "s?___PROXY_HOST1___?$PROXY_HOST1?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_HOST2___?$PROXY_HOST2?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_HOST3___?$PROXY_HOST3?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_HOST4___?$PROXY_HOST4?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s?___PROXY_HOST5___?$PROXY_HOST5?g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Но небходимо чтобы можно было передать 4 или 3 пары переменных PROXY_PATH/HOST 
вместо 5, и nginx работал.

Может кто подскажет вариант через цикл? Или варивант с генерацией блока `location /` на основе заданных переменных.

Comment: [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643737/178576)

Comment: Пользуйтесь возможностью подключения доп. файлов, а вот сам такой файл каждый раз генерируйте, опираясь на количество входных данных.